# HP Z Turbo G2 drive not running in NVMe mode

Tags: hard-drive, nvme

I just got a used HP z440 workstation. It came with a 256 gig Samsung MZHPU256HCGL-000H1 hard drive. The drive is loaded into an HP Z Turbo G2 card. The card has a silkscreen on it of MS-4365 so I'm pretty sure that it is the G2. The card is loaded into slot 4 as recommended. The bios is booting in UEFI mode and legacy boot is disabled.

I threw a fresh copy of Windows 10 x64 on it and updated everything including bios and all drivers. The drive does not seem to run in NVMe mode and I'm not sure why. As far as I can tell the drive is NVMe capable. The G2 card is NVMe capable. The work station is NVMe capable, yet every different way that I check it is not using NVMe. The Device manager and Crystal Disk info both show that the interface is not NVMe.

How do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: [Your SSD is a SATA SSD](https://smarthdd.com/database/SAMSUNG-MZHPU256HCGL-000H1/UXM62H1Q/). It appears that a specific model was sold as a SATA or a NVMe drive.  The same SSD cannot be both.  All you have done is plugged a SATA drive into a HP Z Turbo G2 card, which while is PCIe, the drive itself is SATA.

Comment: @Ramhound That's the answer, why not post it as such?

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the reply, I did not catch that there were two interfaces under the same part number.

Comment: @Ramhound: I don't really trust that particular site. It's not a direct hardware spec site, it's a collection of reports from SMART tools – and I have a feeling that report is just from another person who has exactly the same problem OP has, who ran the tool through the same kind of storage card. (HP docs say that G1 was a SATA card but G2 is supposed to be NVMe.)

Comment: @u1686_grawity - It’s the only explanation that makes sense.